# C++ class with compiler enforced unique ownership semantics for objects

Tags: c++

Is there any way to write a C++ class such that the compiler will enforce unique ownership semantics on the objects?

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Like `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: Well, you could make the ctor private and friend `make_unique`. But let me say, there is really no legit reason to restrict in what fashion someone owns your class. That's up to them. This is fundamentally against good design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Simply disable copy/assignment and enable move.

```
struct unique_thing
{
  unique_thing() = default;  // you can create me
  unique_thing(unique_thing&&) = default; // and move me
  unique_thing(unique_thing const&) = delete; // but not copy me

  unique_thing& operator=(unique_thing&&) = default; // you may move-assign me
  unique_thing& operator=(unique_thing const&) = delete; // but not copy-assign me
};
```

Which we can boil down to a handy base class (note: virtual destructors not necessary because no-one will ever own an object through this class):

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cassert>

struct only_moveable
{
  protected:
  constexpr only_moveable() noexcept = default;
  constexpr only_moveable(only_moveable&&) noexcept = default;
  constexpr only_moveable& operator=(only_moveable&&) noexcept {};
};

struct MyClass : only_moveable
{
};


int main()
{
  // creatable
  MyClass a;

  // move-constructible
  MyClass b = std::move(a);

  // move-assignable
  a = std::move(b);

  // not copy-constructible
  assert((not std::is_copy_constructible<MyClass>::value));

  // not copy-assignable
  assert((not std::is_copy_assignable<MyClass>::value));  
}
```

some common models of this idiom are:

1. `std::unique_ptr<>`
2. `std::thread`
3. `std::future<>`
4. `std::unique_lock<>`
5. `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket`

Comment: I'd add `std::thread`, `std::unique_lock` and some more `std::` and common `boost::` examples before referring to Boost.Asio.

Comment: Btw, you don't need to delete copy ctor and copy `=`. They are not declared implicitely in precense of user-defined (including `default`ed) move ctor and move `=`.

Comment: that slope is glorious

Comment: So, including a `std::unique_ptr` member in my class will this achieve the same result?

Comment: @bosonix yes. but don't add one unless you need one!

Comment: @lisyarus fair point. It just sprang to mind as I use asio a lot. Will update